# Sports winning percentage distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution, independence, mean

I am doing a study where I am measuring parity in sports.  To do this I am looking at how well a year's winning percentages (WP) are distributed.  I am currently comparing them to a binomial distribution, but since each team's WP is directly related to the WP of its competitors, I worry that I'm missing out on a better model.

Is there something better than the standard binomial distribution for this kind of interdependent model?

Comment: Such distribution will have smaller variance. Try Hypergeometric.